# would and will & mastering spoken English

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I have tried understanding the above umpteen times but yet unable to use it in the right place. I have been reading but find myself to be stuck in midst of conversation.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... do you want to know about the difference between "will" and "would"? By the way, if you're still learning English, you can also ask questions at the [English Language Learners site](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

The answer I give is not a grammatical one, since that is not the topic, but I can give you a little hint that can help you.

Use **would** for anything that is not real, imaginary, not happened, not happening or dreaming, imagining.

Like:

> That would be great! (It didn't happen but it would be great if it
>   happened)
>
> I would study more. (It is not happening/it's not real. If I were you
>   I would study more)
>
> Then, I would do this (dreaming about something).

Use **will** when you decide to do something at the time of speaking.

> I will buy some potato chips downstairs. (you are watching TV and
>   think it is a good idea and decided to buy them)
>
> I think I will give it a go tonight. (you will try it tonight, that's
>   what you decided, possible)

Not grammatical answers but when speaking these should be OK. Otherwise, there are huge differences between **will** and **would**.